# Hooking into windows file access

Tags: windows, hook

Is it possible to hook into Windows loading or saving files (no matter how the file is opened like notepad word etc.) to modify the file on the fly?

For example to encode/decode it on the fly?

Would code need administrative permissions to launch?

Answer (score 0):

You probably will have to write a driver. See if you can get a hold of Filemon's source, there is a lot to learn there.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use something like [madCodeHook](http://madcodehook.com/) to intercept file read/writes and to install your dll into every process. I've used this technique to record print jobs for billing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to write an Installable File System driver.  The [Installable File System Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/ifskit/default.mspx) from Microsoft contains a couple of sample drivers, including the one used by Filemon.  Unfortunately, I do not believe you can access those API's without the IFS Kit.

Answer (score -1):

avoid madCodeHook (not profesdional)
use standard api hooking mechanisms (Richter and Microsoft D  mainly)

Comment: What sort of "standard api hooking" are you referring to?