# Redirecting File/Path access to a different folder in C#

Tags: c#

We have some legacy code (console executable) that is called by our web application which has hard coded absolute paths to the file system for accessing certain files when it is run. This has limited our web application to a single instance per server. Is there any way to redirect a process/application's file access to a different folder (maybe a way to force it to use some virtual file system)?

For example: The executable may look for a file in "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webappname\schemas". Can we force all references to that path to point to "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapp2\schemas" instead?

Comment: Can't you update the console application so that it's not hardcoded? Perhaps add a setting in the configuration file that specifies the base path?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have access to the source code, do you? If you don't better that you write a new one. If you do, just update the paths to take a command line argument for example, instead of having a hardcoded path. In hindsight, it was a poor programming decision to have a web application have hardcoded paths to follow, IMO. TL;DR: do you have access to the source code or not?

Comment: Don't have access to easily edit that application or that would definitely be what we would do.

Comment: 100% agree that there were poor decisions made but all of that was before my time. The hard coded paths that are a problem though are not in the web application but in other executables that the web application calls. Those applications reach back into the web application's file system which is the mess we are left with, unfortunately.

Comment: That puts a damper on your goal, as it's pretty much impossible without the source code to change that path. However, if it's an option or if it's a one-time reference pointing that you need (for example, you just need to upload the files), then it's better to write a script that switches the content of both folders and then call this application. However, this is a very volatile and hacky approach, bad results and practice notwithstanding.

Comment: Are you asking "can we force all references by each instance to that path to point to a different path, not necessarily the same for each instance?"

Comment: Les, yes, I believe that sums it up pretty well.

Comment: If it is a one-time hack, would you be able to just use [mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx) to create a junction at the old path to point to the new path?

Comment: Two approaches I can think of, but which may not meet your need.  You can mount a file system on a directory in both Windows (7+) and Linux.  But that would just be a switch from one hard-code to another singleton location.  The other approach is to "detours", but that is very complex and affects the whole system, not just your app.

Comment: Then links/mounts will be a problem.

Comment: Upvoting this. I'd be very impressed if this can be done this way as I have some legacy C# software in the office that might be revived if such an approach is possible. Admittedly, I have faced the same position a while back but I just wrote a Python script to do what I described above. Not the best, but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

There might be two approaches. The first one is definitely easier.

**By modifying the executable**

If the application is written in .Net, use a decompiler like the [one from 9Rays.Net](http://www.9rays.net/), decompile the code, and make modifications. This might also work for Java.

If it's a native application, open the application in a hex editor, locate the string and change it. It has to keep the same length, however you can use a null terminal `\0` to "shorten" it.

**Using C#**

Crate a launcher for the application, which gets called instead, and hooks into [read/write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447856/hooking-into-windows-file-access) calls to modify the paths. This can be done in C#, and you can find [resources on the Internet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27637/EasyHook-The-reinvention-of-Windows-API-hooking) for it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found an answer. I got it to work in .Net, I don't know if it will help for any other languages. Inspiration came from this blog: http://blog.didierstevens.com/2006/07/07/viewing-strings-in-executables/

I downloaded Mcaffee's BinText 3.03 (http://www.mcafee.com/us/downloads/free-tools/bintext.aspx), and ran it on my test EXE. I searched through the list, and found the string I wanted to replace. This gives you a file position offset. My string was at 0x73F according to BinText. The following code replaced the first two characters of my string with "AK". With a little rework, you could do actual string removal, instead of a simple 1:1 character replacement.

```
{
  string file = "TrashV1.exe"; // Input EXE
  string fileout = "TrashV2.exe";
  File.Delete(fileout);

  byte[] barr = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
  int offset = 0x73e; // NOTE! This is one LESS than the offset that MCaffee reported!

  string replace = "AK";
  var enc = new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding();
  byte[] unicode = enc.GetBytes(replace);
  for (int i = 0; i < unicode.Length; i++)
  {
    barr[offset + i] = unicode[i];
  }

  File.WriteAllBytes(fileout, barr);
}
```

TrashV1.exe: `STACK_OVERFLOW`

TrashV2.exe: `AKACK_OVERFLOW`